# Open Xcode project programmatically in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

How would you go about opening an Xcode project programmatically from within a macOSX app.

I have a URL object with the path to the xcodeProj file.

Would you execute a script within the app or use an API?

What API could be used for this?

I don't want to use NSOpenPanel because I don't want the user to have to go chose the file to open.

Comment: What's wrong with executing a shell script `open PROJECT_FILE`?

Comment: Nothing just wondering if thats the only available option?

Comment: Apparently you can use `NSWorkspace`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can use NSWorkspace to do this instead of writing a shell script.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace

`NSWorkspace.shared.openFile(url.path, withApplication: "Xcode")`